# Running Google Cloud DocumentAI sample code on Python returned the error 503

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am trying the example from the Google repo:
https://github.com/googleapis/python-documentai/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/quickstart_sample.py

I have an error:

```
metadata=[('x-goog-request-params', 'name=projects/my_proj_id/locations/us/processors/my_processor_id'), ('x-goog-api-client', 'gl-python/3.8.10 grpc/1.38.1 gax/1.30.0 gapic/1.0.0')]), last exception: 503 DNS resolution failed for service: https://us-documentai.googleapis.com/v1/
```

My full code:

```
from google.cloud import documentai_v1 as documentai
import os

# TODO(developer): Uncomment these variables before running the sample.
project_id= '123456789'
location = 'us' # Format is 'us' or 'eu'
processor_id = '1a23345gh823892' #  Create processor in Cloud Console
file_path = 'document.jpg'

os.environ['GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER'] = 'native'


def quickstart(project_id: str, location: str, processor_id: str, file_path: str):

    # You must set the api_endpoint if you use a location other than 'us', e.g.:
    opts = {}
    if location == "eu":
        opts = {"api_endpoint": "eu-documentai.googleapis.com"}

    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=opts)

    # The full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
    # projects/project-id/locations/location/processor/processor-id
    # You must create new processors in the Cloud Console first
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/processors/{processor_id}:process"

    # Read the file into memory
    with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
        image_content = image.read()

    document = {"content": image_content, "mime_type": "image/jpeg"}

    # Configure the process request
    request = {"name": name, "raw_document": document}

    result = client.process_document(request=request)
    document = result.document

    document_pages = document.pages

    # For a full list of Document object attributes, please reference this page: https://googleapis.dev/python/documentai/latest/_modules/google/cloud/documentai_v1beta3/types/document.html#Document

    # Read the text recognition output from the processor
    print("The document contains the following paragraphs:")
    for page in document_pages:
        paragraphs = page.paragraphs
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            print(paragraph)
            paragraph_text = get_text(paragraph.layout, document)
            print(f"Paragraph text: {paragraph_text}")


def get_text(doc_element: dict, document: dict):
    """
    Document AI identifies form fields by their offsets
    in document text. This function converts offsets
    to text snippets.
    """
    response = ""
    # If a text segment spans several lines, it will
    # be stored in different text segments.
    for segment in doc_element.text_anchor.text_segments:
        start_index = (
            int(segment.start_index)
            if segment in doc_element.text_anchor.text_segments
            else 0
        )
        end_index = int(segment.end_index)
        response += document.text[start_index:end_index]
    return response

def main ():
    quickstart (project_id = project_id, location = location, processor_id = processor_id, file_path = file_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

FYI, on the Google Cloud website it stated that the endpoint is:

```
https://us-documentai.googleapis.com/v1/projects/123456789/locations/us/processors/1a23345gh823892:process
```

I can use the web interface to run DocumentAI so it is working. I just have the problem with Python code.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to change values from `us` to `eu` in 6th line? `location = 'us' # Format is 'us' or 'eu'` In all you config you have eu but there you have us. Do you have the same issue with this change?

Comment: I will have the permission denied problem. The project is set on the 'us' location already.

Comment: So in your code everywhere have `us` and nowhere `eu`. Are you are running this code from your local machine or from GCP console? Could you provide longer error log or this is whole error? Did you create Service Acc with Document AI permissions? Could you try to use code from [GCP Document AI Docs](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/libraries#cloud-console) with Python examples?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the `GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER` environment variable to be the root cause. Did you try with the corresponding line commented out? Why was it added in your code?